# Android 9-patch scaling affected by the density folder that it resides in

Tags: android, image, scaling

I have a 9-patch image with a 1px gray border around it as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnq0U.png

I was under the impression that I could stick this in any single density folder without issue. Now I know that doing so will result in tiny (less round) corners on high density screens, and large (more round) corners on low density screens.

Problem is, when I stick it in a single density folder, it seems like Android is scaling some of the non-scalable areas. For example, when I stick it in the hdpi folder and run it on an xhdpi or xxhdpi phone, the 1px gray border becomes 2 or 3 pixels wide.

Why is it scaling the border? Note that the problem is fixed when I distribute the image to every density folder. But I'm still confused because I thought 9-patch is only supposed to scale the areas in the bounds of the black lines, no matter which density folder it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the 9-patch isn't to handle scaling; it's to handle multiple sized buttons or whatnot. The non-stretch portions of your 9-patch image will still be scaled according to the normal scaling rules. To make your image look right, you should provide prescaled versions and put them into the various density folders.